# Determining full XHR request URL on a Google Chrome XHR Breakpoint

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

I am initiating a jQuery ajax ($.ajax) post, within the Google Chrome browser.

I have setup a  XHR breakpoint in the "***XHR Breakpoints***" section of the "***Scripts***" tab within the Developer Tools.

The criteria of the breakpoint is "get" ie. I want the debugger to break on all XHR requests which contain the word "get" in them (somePage.asmx/getListOfAnimals) is an example.

The breakpoint is being correctly hit, however I am unable to determine what the **exact URL** that is being requested.

I realize I can remove the breakpoint and see what URL is being requested from the "Network" tab, but I want to know this at the time the breakpoint is hit.

I have tried stepping through the XHR request once it has been hit in Chrome, but I must be missing a Javascript object/property which contains the fully requested URL.

Google Chrome has detected that the XHR requested URL contains "get" but how do I get to this **URL** from within the debug session before the request is made?

Comment: Are you able to break before the XHR.open() method? The 2nd parameter to the open() method should be the exact url of the request.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Just tested again in the latest chrome and seems to be workign fine I can see the actual URL being requested.